# VBA Excel: How can I store a real number but display a rounded number in a textbox?

Tags: excel, textbox, vba

I am calculating a bunch of values like density and volume. I show them on a form and when the user clicks "Update", I save that number to a worksheet.

There are a lot of numbers, so I want to neatly display the rounded version without losing the better precision number.

Like

```
Sub SetDensity()

  dim rDensity as double

  rDensity = 0.78022134

  me.txtDensity = Format(rDensity,"0.00")  ' user sees 0.78

End Sub
```

When data is finally written to worksheet, I want to be able to store the full precision like:

```
Sub UpdateWS()    
  Sheets(1).Range("A:A") = me.txtDensity   ' put value 0.78022134 on worksheet
End Sub
```

Does the textbox have an alternate field where I can store the full number without displaying it, or do I need a hidden textbox for every real number that contains the full value?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `TextBox`'s `Tag` property to store the value. Here's a simple example:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Me.TextBox1.Tag = 2.38232
Me.TextBox1.Value = Format(Me.TextBox1.Tag, "0.00")
Me.TextBox2.Tag = 4.99999
Me.TextBox2.Value = Format(Me.TextBox2.Tag, "0.00")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox Me.TextBox1.Tag * Me.TextBox2.Tag
End Sub
```

What you ideally do in this situation is create an instance of a userform and pass the values into it as `Properties`, and then when the user clicks "OK" you get the computed value back out as another `Form Property`. Here's a [post from my site](http://yoursumbuddy.com/a-flexible-vba-chooser-form/), and one from [Daily Dose of Excel](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/07/22/passing-arguments-to-a-userform/), that give you the general idea. You could use these concepts and modify to work with textboxes.

Comment: I just read some of your other questions, and now really encourage you to take the 2nd approach I mentioned, i.e., instantiating a UserForm class, passing data to it's properties, and passing the result back out. For the most thorough discussion of this I know of, read [Professional Excel Development](http://www.amazon.ca/Professional-Excel-Development-Definitive-Applications/dp/0321508793).

Comment: Thanks Doug. These are both great ideas. I am dying to try out classes and have started creating them, but since it's crunch time I don't really have time to follow through. The Tag Property will work well for now until I can get more time.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Since it sounds like this works for you, please help me in my quest for my next 10k by accepting. :)

Comment: I just want to add that I got the book Professional Excel Development and it is extremely helpful. Also, my decision in the end was to do the work I would have done in the beginning if I had known how.  That is, I created a class that mirrors the info in the form (plus extra fields). Every time I show info on the form (like .8014), I store the actual value (like .8014278933) in the class. I also store all kinds of helpful flags and calculations in the class. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.